# How to populate a form box with javascript based on other form box inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with four number inputs: hourly wage, hours worked, number of weeks, and salary.

I want to automatically fill-in the salary box based on the inputs from wage, hours, and weeks boxes.

So in theory, if hourly `wage = 15`, `hours worked = 40`, and `number of weeks = 52` then the salary form box should automatically be set to "31200"

Any simple way to do this with javascript? I have tried a few different methods and can't seem to get it to work.

If it helps, I have already set all the form boxes to variables:

```
var wageBox = document.forms[0].wage;
var hoursBox = document.forms[0].hours;
var weeksBox = document.forms[0].weeks;
var salaryBox = document.forms[0].salary;
```

Edit: sorry, here's the HTML form code:

```
<fieldset id="incomeinfo">
            <label for="wage">
              Hourly wage:
              <input type="number" id="wage" name="wage" placeholder="e.g. 15.00">
            </label>
            <label for="Hours">
              Hours worked each week:
              <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" value="40" placeholder="e.g. 40">
            </label>
            <label for="Weeks">
              Number of weeks a year:
              <input type="number" id="weeks" name="weeks" value="52" placeholder="e.g. 52">
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="salary">
              Salary:
              <input type="number" id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="e.g. 31200" required>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
```

Comment: What methods have you used to try to get it to work?  Can we see those?  Also can we see html?

Comment: Adding to @Nate's comment: can you also add a snippet of the HTML form to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a event for when the inputs change and calculate the salary based off of their values. Quick mock up.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/6uatoyd2/

JS:

```
function calculateSalary () {

    // Get all values we need to calculate
    var wage = parseInt(document.getElementById('wage').value, 10);
    var hours = parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value, 10);
    var weeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value, 10);

    // Calculate salary
    var salary = wage * hours * weeks;

    // Only update salary if we got number
    if (!isNaN(salary)) {
        document.getElementById('salary').value = salary;
    }

}

// Get all inputs, loop and attach change event with calculateSalary handler
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var index = 0, length = inputs.length
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    inputs[index].addEventListener('change', calculateSalary);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="wage" placeholder="wage" />
<input type="text" id="hours" placeholder="hours" />
<input type="text" id="weeks" placeholder="weeks" />
<input type="text" id="salary" placeholder="salary" />
```

EDIT: Updated fiddle using your HTML. Same code works.

http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/6uatoyd2/1/

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for the quick response! 

I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Comment: I am new here, so weird question: how do I set my question to answered and your response to the correct answer?

Or can you not do that?

Comment: No problem. Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. that will mark it as the accepted answer.